Can't connect to Oracle 19c db with SSH tunnel using python
I am not an expert neither on Oracle or Python, so maybe the answer is obvious but I still couldn't find the answer to my problem on forums.
I have an SSH connection to Oracle 19c db on SQL developer and DBeaver, but I cant connect with Python.
I tried many thing like checking if thick mode is needed but got different errors.
In thin mode the SSH tunnel created but the Oracle connection run into errors.
In thick mode it freezed.
The code snippets are below.
Do you have any idea where is the problem and what could be a solution?
Thanks
Thin mode:
class SSHTunnel:

    def __init__(self, ssh_host, ssh_port, ssh_user, ssh_key_file, remote_bind_host, remote_bind_port,
                 local_bind_port=1522):
        self.ssh_host = ssh_host
        self.ssh_port = ssh_port
        self.ssh_user = ssh_user
        self.ssh_key_file = ssh_key_file
        self.remote_bind_host = remote_bind_host
        self.remote_bind_port = remote_bind_port
        self.local_bind_port = local_bind_port
        self.client = None
        self.forward_tunnel = None

    def __enter__(self):
        logging.debug("Setting up SSH Tunnel")
        self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(self.ssh_key_file)
        self.client.connect(self.ssh_host, port=self.ssh_port, username=self.ssh_user, pkey=private_key,timeout=3)

        # Establish the tunnel to the remote database
        self.forward_tunnel = self.client.get_transport().open_channel(
            "direct-tcpip",
            (self.remote_bind_host, self.remote_bind_port),
            ('127.0.0.1', self.local_bind_port)
        )

        logging.debug(f"SSH Tunnel established on local port {self.local_bind_port}")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        logging.debug("Tearing down SSH Tunnel")
        if self.forward_tunnel:
            self.forward_tunnel.close()
        if self.client:
            self.client.close()


class OracleConnection:

    def __init__(self, username, password, local_bind_port, service_name):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.local_bind_port = local_bind_port
        self.service_name = service_name
        self.connection = None

    def __enter__(self):
        logging.debug("Setting up Oracle connection")
        dsn = oracledb.makedsn("127.0.0.1", self.local_bind_port, service_name=self.service_name)
        logging.debug(f"Connecting to DSN: {dsn}")
        self.connection = oracledb.connect(user=self.username, password=self.password, dsn=dsn, disable_oob=True)
        logging.debug("Oracle connection established")
        return self.connection

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        logging.debug("Tearing down Oracle connection")
        if self.connection:
            self.connection.close()


def main():

    ssh_host = "111.111.111.111"
    ssh_port = 22
    ssh_user = "one"
    ssh_key_file = "c:\\Users\\ssh-key.key"

    remote_bind_host = "12.7.0.41"
    remote_bind_port = 1521
    oracle_user = "system"
    oracle_password = "password"
    oracle_service_name = "oracledb.sub1.vcn03.oraclevcn.com"
    local_bind_port = 1522 

    with SSHTunnel(ssh_host, ssh_port, ssh_user, ssh_key_file,remote_bind_host, remote_bind_port, local_bind_port) as ssh_tunnel:
        with OracleConnection(oracle_user, oracle_password, ssh_tunnel.local_bind_port, oracle_service_name) as connection:
           logging.debug("Successfully connected to the Oracle database!")

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table")
            for row in cursor:
                print(row)

            # Close the cursor
            cursor.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Errors:
oracledb.exceptions.OperationalError: DPY-6005: cannot connect to database (CONNECTION_ID=rid).
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it


Thick:
class SSHTunnel:

    def __init__(self, ssh_host, ssh_port, ssh_user, ssh_key_file, remote_bind_host, remote_bind_port, local_bind_port=1522):
        self.ssh_host = ssh_host
        self.ssh_port = ssh_port
        self.ssh_user = ssh_user
        self.ssh_key_file = ssh_key_file
        self.remote_bind_host = remote_bind_host
        self.remote_bind_port = remote_bind_port
        self.local_bind_port = local_bind_port
        self.client = None
        self.channel = None

    def __enter__(self):
        logging.debug("Setting up SSH Tunnel")
        self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.client.connect(
            self.ssh_host, port=self.ssh_port, username=self.ssh_user, key_filename=self.ssh_key_file
        )
        
        self.channel = self.client.invoke_shell()
        self.channel.send('uname -a\n')
        
        buff = ''
        while not buff.endswith('# '):
            resp = self.channel.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
            buff += resp
        logging.debug(f"SSH Shell Prompt: {buff}")

        self.forward_tunnel = self.client.get_transport().open_channel(
            "direct-tcpip",
            (self.remote_bind_host, self.remote_bind_port),
            ('127.0.0.1', self.local_bind_port)
        )

        logging.debug(f"SSH Tunnel established on local port {self.local_bind_port}")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        logging.debug("Tearing down SSH Tunnel")
        if self.forward_tunnel:
            self.forward_tunnel.close()
        if self.channel:
            self.channel.close()
        if self.client:
            self.client.close()

class OracleConnection:

    def __init__(self, username, password, local_bind_port, service_name):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.local_bind_port = local_bind_port
        self.service_name = service_name
        self.connection = None

    def __enter__(self):
        logging.debug("Setting up Oracle connection in thick mode")
        
        oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir="c:\\Program Files\\Oracle Client for Microsoft Tools\\t")  

        dsn = oracledb.makedsn("127.0.0.1", self.local_bind_port, service_name=self.service_name)
        logging.debug(f"Connecting to DSN: {dsn}")
        self.connection = oracledb.connect(user=self.username, password=self.password, dsn=dsn)
        logging.debug("Oracle connection established")
        return self.connection

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        logging.debug("Tearing down Oracle connection")
        if self.connection:
            self.connection.close()

def main():

    ssh_host = "111.111.111.111"
    ssh_port = 22
    ssh_user = "one"
    ssh_key_file = "c:\\Users\\ssh-key.key"

    remote_bind_host = "12.7.0.41"
    remote_bind_port = 1521
    oracle_user = "system"
    oracle_password = "password"
    oracle_service_name = "oracledb.sub1.vcn03.oraclevcn.com"
    local_bind_port = 1522 

    with SSHTunnel(ssh_host, ssh_port, ssh_user, ssh_key_file,remote_bind_host, remote_bind_port, local_bind_port) as ssh_tunnel:
        with OracleConnection(oracle_user, oracle_password, ssh_tunnel.local_bind_port, oracle_service_name) as connection:
           logging.debug("Successfully connected to the Oracle database!")

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table")
            for row in cursor:
                print(row)

            # Close the cursor
            cursor.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Errors:
DEBUG
.transport:[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
DEBUG
.transport:[chan 0] Sesch channel 0 request ok
DEBUG
.transport:[chan 0] Unhandled channel request "keepalive@openssh.com"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Users\ssh.py", line 1995, in <module>
DEBUG
.transport:[chan 0] EOF received (0)
DEBUG
.transport:[chan 0] EOF sent (0)
main()
File "D:\Users\ssh.py", line 402, in main
with SSHTunnel(
File "D:\Users\ssh.py", line 333, in enter
resp = self.channel.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 697, in recv
out = self.in_buffer.read(nbytes, self.timeout)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\buffered_pipe.py", line 150, in read
self._cv.wait(timeout)
File "C:\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 355, in wait
waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
DEBUG.transport in transport thread



Modified code with SSHTunnel:
Here is the code's connecting part:
import oracledb
import paramiko
import sshtunnel
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder #Run pip install sshtunnel
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker #Run pip install sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import psycopg2
import os
import time
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


def main():
    ssh_host = "111.111.111"
    ssh_port = 22
    ssh_user = "ssh_user"
    ssh_key_file = "c:\\Users\\ssh-key.key"

    remote_bind_host = "12.5.21"
    remote_bind_port = 1521

    oracle_user = "or_user"
    oracle_password = "or_pswd"
    oracle_service_name = "db.oraclevcn.com"

    with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
            (ssh_host, ssh_port),
            ssh_username=ssh_user,
            ssh_pkey=ssh_key_file,
            remote_bind_address=(
                    remote_bind_host,
                    remote_bind_port),
            local_bind_address=(
                    '127.0.0.1',
                    1522)) as server:

        server.start()
        print('Server connected via SSH')

        local_port = str(server.local_bind_port)
        engine = create_engine(f'oracle+oracledb://{oracle_user}:{oracle_password}@127.0.0.1:{local_port}/{oracle_service_name}')

        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        print('Connected to Oracle')
        session = Session()

        result = session.execute(text("SELECT * FROM all_users"))
        result_exists = result.fetchone()[0]
        session.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

And the end part of debuging + errors:
Server connected via SSH
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
Connected to Oracle
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Received global request "hostkeys-00@openssh.com"
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Rejecting "hostkeys-00@openssh.com" global request from server.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Debug msg: b'/home/opc/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding'
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 0 opened.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 0] EOF sent (0)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Dropping user packet because connection is dead.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Dropping user packet because connection is dead.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 279, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_address
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 242, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._connect_phase_one
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 400, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._process_message
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/protocol.pyx", line 379, in oracledb.thin_impl.Protocol._process_message
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/messages.pyx", line 1875, in oracledb.thin_impl.ConnectMessage.process
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\oracledb\errors.py", line 182, in _raise_err
    raise error.exc_type(error) from cause
oracledb.exceptions.OperationalError: DPY-6003: SID "db.oraclevcn.com" is not registered with the listener at host "127.0.0.1" port 1522. (Similar to ORA-12505)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3300, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 449, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1263, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 712, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 179, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 177, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 390, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 674, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 900, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 896, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 643, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 620, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\oracledb\connection.py", line 1158, in connect
    return conn_class(dsn=dsn, pool=pool, params=params, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\oracledb\connection.py", line 541, in __init__
    impl.connect(params_impl)
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 381, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 377, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl.connect
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 337, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_params
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 318, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_description
  File "src\\oracledb\\impl/thin/connection.pyx", line 284, in oracledb.thin_impl.ThinConnImpl._connect_with_address
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\oracledb\errors.py", line 182, in _raise_err
    raise error.exc_type(error) from cause
oracledb.exceptions.OperationalError: DPY-6005: cannot connect to database (CONNECTION_ID=53uh4nd==).
DPY-6003: SID "db.oraclevcn.com" is not registered with the listener at host "127.0.0.1" port 1522. (Similar to ORA-12505)

I saw in SQLAlchemy "create_engine" documentation that it uses cx_oracle, but it is not available in newer python only oracledb is available. In other cases they were interchangeable, maybe here it is not working.
I tried with dsn too, but I got error again:
dsn = f"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT={local_port}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME={oracle_service_name})))"
engine = create_engine(f'oracle+oracledb://{oracle_user}:{oracle_password}@/?dsn={dsn}')

sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError) DPY-4011: the database or network closed the connection


Your code only sets up the forwarding between the client and the server.
But it does not actually open the local port and does not forward it to the SSH tunnel transport.
I suggest that you use sshtunnel module that does it for you and generally simplifies your code a lot. Some example:
Connecting to PostgreSQL database through SSH tunneling in Python

Problem solved!
The solution was in the oracledb documentation: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#dpy-4011 .
The Python oracledb connection was possible only in thick mode in my case.
I had to update or install (right now it meant download and unzip only) the Oracle Instant Client: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html .
And insert this code somewhere before the connection script:
# Path to your Oracle Instant Client libraries
instant_client_path = r"C:\\Program Files\\instantclient_23_4"

# Initialize the Oracle Client in Thick mode
oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=instant_client_path)


I'm not sure I understand. Did you have to combine my tunnel solution and the new client? Or did you use the new client only (and the tunnel was not needed)? If the first, please consider merging your part of the solution into mine answer.
